# Loop Cells to check hours passed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a macro that will loop through a column to check the hours compared to the current time.  The date/time is entered into the cell via a button on a form and is formatted mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss and what I want to do is run a macro once every hour to find which cells in the column are older than 6 hours and needs to work even if it goes into the next day. I tried one small piece of code that I found but the results were incorrect.

```
For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
If rCell < Hour(Now) - 6 Then
MsgBox rCell.Address, rCell.Value
ElseIf rCell = "" Then Exit Sub
Else
```

Comment: If you're trying to find a macro use Search option on this website or use google. If you've tried anything share that.

Comment: have you tried replacing hour(now) with now - timevalue("06:00:00")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datetime values in Excel are stored as decimal.  All you have to do is compare the difference between your cell's value and `Now` is greater than `6.0/24`

```
For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    If Now - rCell.Value > (6.0/24) Then
          MsgBox rCell.Address, rCell.Value
    ElseIf rCell = "" Then Exit Sub
    Else
......
```